# Geometry nodes - separate collection objects by length

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want the objects in the collection to be distributed according to their length along one of the axes. Is there any way to get this information (y-axis length) about the objects in the collection?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Currently the "Collection" instancing is a bit limited, you can't control the relative weight of each member of the collection so it's next to impossible to reliably instance every member of a collection at least once, nor exactly once before the other ones repeat. You also can't extract how many objects there is in a given collection to set the number of point instancers accordingly. In the meantime this would be achieved somewhat easily in Animation Nodes if you're open to that

Comment: @Gorgious: I think it is possible...i have an idea....i try ;)

Comment: @Chris I would be glad to be wrong :)

Comment: ah damn...bounding box is just for whole geometry, not for point instance :( my idea has been blown away...

Comment: can we get the height/length somehow by gn?

Comment: or maximum of any axis from attribute (one number)?

Comment: One would need to access an instanced object's properties *after* it has been instanced, which is not possible in GN right now afaik.

Comment: if you are open for AN solution, let us know...then we can help ;)